# How do I trigger a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<a href="#" class="button" id="buyme" ></a>  
<a href="#" id="buy" onclick="placeOrder('10');return false;"><span id="please">click me</span></a>

<script>
$('#buyme').click(function() {
    $('#buy').trigger(function(placeOrder('10')));
});
</script>

<script>
function placeOrder(var) {
.....
}
</script>
```

What I want to do is when I click on `#buyme` to trigger the `onclick` from the `#buy` link or to trigger the function from inside `onClick`.

My example doesn't seem to do it. Any ideas?

edit:

for some reason :

```
$('#buyme').click(function() {
$("#buy").click();
});
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the function yourself:

```
$('#buyme').click(function() {
    placeOrder('10');
});
```

You could also trigger the click event of the button and let it call the function (seems a bit backwards though):

```
$('#buyme').click(function() {
    $("#buy").click();
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the inner 'function('?

Comment: There's a potential issue of context here.  Calling it independently is not the same as the element being clicked if `this` is used.

Comment: I did seconds after the post - refresh :)

Comment: @kingjiv, agreed (that's why I added the second example). Based on the code provided, there is no context issue though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buyme").click(function(){
    $("#buy").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/). According to docs, calling it without an argument triggers the event.

```
$('#buy').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit: `function(placeOrder('10'))` is invalid. Replace it with:

```
$('#buy').click();
```